# Download when needed (NAS like) client for cloud service

Tags: desktop-client, portable, cloud-storage

I want to know if there's a service that could do the trick for me. I want a client for a cloud service like dropbox, Drive, OneDrive etc, which would only download the file and all the child files needed to the computer when I open it, and offload those to the server when I'm done, just for the purpose of freeing space in the local drive.

More or less like a NAS would do, where you can see all the items, but they're stored somewhere else unless you open them and the download/stream begins.

I would prefer freeware, but if a paid one is the optimal option, I'd go with that.

**Must have:**

1. Ability to download files requested by other software (Like an .exe which needs config files or additional data).
2. Selective sync (In case I want some files pre-downloaded).
3. GUI and some type of listing or file explorer to see all your downloadable content.
4. Offload temporary files to the cloud service to free storage when not used.

**Would be nice to have:**

1. Portable version.
2. Recent and/or frequent updates.

Comment: Are you OK with mounting a WebDAV remote folder as a drive on your computer?

Comment: The downside is that my main will have to stay on 24/7... But it's better than nothing. Can you tell me more about WebDAV? I researched for a bit and don't really understand how it would work. If the files would keep stored, if there's some type of GUI. I think it's somewhat similar to a NAS, but for external connections?

Comment: With WebDAV, everything is stored on the remote server. Nothing is stored locally (or only temporary caches). Only when you read or write a file, or browse the file system, network transfers occur.

Answer (score -1):

I found a piece of software called Expandrive http://www.expandrive.com/

It is NOT portable, but what it does is map the cloud service you selected onto a network drive in your computer, like a WebDAV or NAS would do. The sync occurs in the background and the files are not downloaded until they are requested by any software.

It is a PAID software and it's not cheap.

Does anyone has any new software to show me?